# Закрыть вопросы по маркетингу и монетизации

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, вопросы, закрытие-вопросов

Предлагаю закрыть все или почти все вопросы по следующим меткам:

- [маркетинг](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3)
- [монетизация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f)
- [реклама](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b0)
- [раскрутка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0)
- [платежи](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b8) (кроме вопросов по программированию платежных систем)

В большинстве своем они не соответствуют тематике сайта. Закрывать нужно как новые, так и старые вопросы, чтобы даже дурной пример не подавать.

Comment: Добавлю, что большинство вопросов следует закрыть за широкие формулировки, приглашение к обсуждению и отсутствие однозначных ответов.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Пробежался, что можно было, спас, остальное закрыл.

Answer (score 7):

SEO штука не самая приятная, но в принципе эта метка и вопросы нужны.

А вот остальные - да, я за то, чтобы их снести.

Там суммарно 33 вопроса получается.

Можно еще в описание меток добавить: "никогда не задавайте вопросы по этой тематике".

Comment: еще нашел «платежи».